# How can i use the line break here?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried a piece of code and it worked good but the problem is it has a file.write value that I want in separated in lines. but its not working.
the code is :

```
start = input('Enter your starting point:')
stop = input('enter your destination:')
count = input('Ticket count:')

p = 10 * int(count) #a + b  
q = 20 * int(count)#a + c
r = 30 * int(count)#a + d
s = 10 * int(count)#b + c
t = 20 * int(count)#b + d
u = 10 * int(count)#c + d

if start == 'a' and stop == 'b':
    file = open(r"C:\Users\the\Desktop\py\2.txt " , 'w+')
    file.write('Location: '+ start +' > '+ stop +\
      'Ticket count: '+ count +\
      'Total fare: ' + str(p))
    file.close()
    print ('Your cost is usd ',p)
elif start == 'a' and stop == 'c':
    file = open(r"C:\Users\the\Desktop\py\2.txt " , 'w+')
    file.write('Location: '+ start +' > '+ stop +\
      'Ticket count: '+ count +\
      'Total fare: ' + str(q))
    file.close()
    print ('Your cost is usd ',q )
elif start == 'a' and stop == 'd':
    file = open(r"C:\Users\the\Desktop\py\2.txt " , 'w+')
    file.write('Location: '+ start +' > '+ stop +\
      'Ticket count: '+ count +\
      'Total fare: ' + str(r))
    file.close()
    print ('Your cost is usd ',r )
elif start == 'b' and stop == 'c':
    file = open(r"C:\Users\the\Desktop\py\2.txt " , 'w+')
    file.write('Location: '+ start +' > '+ stop +\
      'Ticket count: '+ count +\
      'Total fare: ' + str(s))
    file.close()
    print ('Your cost is usd ',s )
elif start == 'b' and stop == 'd':
    file = open(r"C:\Users\the\Desktop\py\2.txt " , 'w+')
    file.write('Location: '+ start +' > '+ stop +\
      'Ticket count: '+ count +\
      'Total fare: ' + str(t))
    file.close()
    print ('Your cost is usd ',t )
elif start == 'c' and stop == 'd':
    file = open(r"C:\Users\the\Desktop\py\2.txt " , 'w+')
    file.write('Location: '+ start +' > '+ stop +\
      'Ticket count: '+ count +\
      'Total fare: ' + str(u))
    file.close()
    print ('Your cost is usd ',u )
else:
    print('you entered wrong values')
```

please give me a solution or fix the code.  one thing to mention that im newbie in python and this is my first program i trying. hope to have this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I you want this piece of code to write in separated lines, you have to add a "\n" at the end of each line:

```
file.write('Location: '+ start +' > '+ stop +\
  'Ticket count: '+ count +\
  'Total fare: ' + str(r)+"\n")
```

For windows you may need "\r\n"